# Connected sets and its properties

Tags: general-topology

Is all points of a connected set is an interior points except the boundaries?and suppose is it has the boundary points then the connected set is closed right?

Answer (score 1):

For any subset $A$ we know that $A = \operatorname{Int}(A) \cup (\operatorname{Bd}(A) \cap A)$, so its interior points together with all points of $A$ that are boundary points. This union is always disjoint, but either part can be empty. E.g. for $A = \mathbb{Q}$ the interior is empty, and all points of $A$ are boundary points, and in $A = (0,1)$ all points are interior points, and no points of $A$ are boundary points (there are boundary points, ($0$ and $1$) but they're not part of $A$.

The equality is easily proved from the definitions. It has nothing to do with $A$ being connected or not. And if $\operatorname{Bd}(A) \subseteq A$, indeed $A$ is closed (regardless of connectedness again).